# Django: check content_type of a request?

Tags: django, http, http-headers

I'd like to know if a request is HTML, CSS, image etc (in middleware).

I've tried:

```
print request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']
```

but that gives me:

```
text/plain
```

for everything, CSS and images alike.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to only be serving text based things through Django.  Static media should be served through your production server. See [this part of the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/)

Secondly, you probably want to be checking the response, not the request.

Comment: You can dynamically generate non-text output with Django. I have used it to generate PNG graphs from model data before, and the docs [demonstrate how to generate PDF output](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/outputting-pdf/).

Comment: It's not that you can't, It's just that, in most cases, you probably shouldn't.  My first django app (django-qimg) demonstrates how you _can_ do it (PIL to generate placeholder images).  Generally I would opt for that happening out of the request/response cycle though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [process_response](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-response), as Issac mentioned, you need to be looking at response.